# JS - Infinite while loop but the condition is already false

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Please help me debug this code. It hangs up when I used the while loop. The case is I want to send a post request when the base64 field is not empty anymore. I can't use setTimeout function because the encoding time is dynamic depends on the file size.

```js
    $(document).on('change','.contract-file', function(){
      var textField = $(this).siblings('input:not(.contract-file-encoded)');
      var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
      var contractId    = $(this).closest('.personal-accordion').find('input[type=hidden].contractId');
      var staffId       = $('input[name=staffId]').val();
      var base64Holder = $(this).siblings('.contract-file-encoded')
      textField.val( fileName ); // show filename
      var input = $(this);

      setTimeout(function(){
        var fileUpload = new FileReader;
        var file = input[0].files[0];
        var image = new Image();

        setTimeout(function(){
          fileUpload.onload = function (e){
            return function (e){
              base64Holder.attr("value",e.target.result);
            }
          }(file);

        fileUpload.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      });  

      while( base64Holder.val().length <= 0 ){
        console.log('encoding...');
      }
      
      var params = {
        _method: 'put',
        contract_id: contractId.val(),
        is_saving_contract_file: 1,
        attribute: { dummy: 'dummy'},
        contract_file: base64Holder.val()
      };

      $.post("/ajax/staffs/"+staffId, params, function(data){
        console.log('Ajax return:');
        console.log(data);
      });

    });
```

Comment: `I can't use setTimeout function` - and yet you use it ... twice ... inappropriately

Comment: Sorry sir just copy pasting some codes from my colleague..

Comment: I mean I can't use setTimeout(function(), delay) because the delay is dynamic(depends on the encoding time of the file). Let say 5Mb file takes 10sec but 1kb does it in 1sec. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is synchronous under the hood so you can't do what are you doing because when the loop is entered js has no time to execute the callback.

Comment: Thanks to point that synch thing, I'm still a newbie js developer. I was wondering if do you have any idea how to make my logic work?